# IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm trying to connect BigQuery Dataset to Databrick and run Script using Pyspark.

Procedures I've done:

- I patched the BigQuery Json API to databrick in dbfs for connection access.
- Then I added spark-bigquery-latest.jar in the cluster library and I ran my Script.

When I run this script, I didn't face any error.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('bq')
    .master('local[4]')
    .config('parentProject', 'google-project-ID')
    .config('spark.jars', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/jarlocation.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
)
df = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/bigqueryapi.json") \
  .option("parentProject", "google-project-ID") \
  .option("project", "Dataset-Name") \
  .option("table","dataset.schema.tablename") \
  .load()
df.show()
```

But Instead of calling a single table in that schema I tried to call all the tables under it using query like:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from google.cloud import bigquery
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('bq')
    .master('local[4]')
    .config('parentProject', 'google-project-ID')
    .config('spark.jars', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/jarlocation.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
)
client = bigquery.Client()
table_list = 'dataset.schema'
tables = client.list_tables(table_list)

for table in tables:
   tlist = tlist.append(table)

for i in tlist:
   sql_query = """select * from `dataset.schema.' + i +'`"""
   df = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/bigqueryapi.json") \
  .option("parentProject", "google-project-ID") \
  .option("project", "Dataset-Name") \
  .option("query", sql_query).load()
  df.show()
```

OR

This Script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('bq')
    .master('local[4]')
    .config('parentProject', 'google-project-ID')
    .config('spark.jars', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/jarlocation.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
)
sql_query = """select * from `dataset.schema.tablename`"""
df = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/bigqueryapi.json") \
  .option("parentProject", "google-project-ID") \
  .option("project", "Dataset-Name") \
  .option("query", sql_query).load()
  df.show()
```

I get this unusual Error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-131090852> in <module>
     35   .option("parentProject", "google-project-ID") \
     36   .option("project", "Dataset-Name") \
---> 37   .option("query", sql_query).load()
     38 #df.show()
     39 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    182             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    183         else:
--> 184             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    185 
    186     @since(1.4)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    131                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    132                 # JVM exception message.
--> 133                 raise_from(converted)
    134             else:
    135                 raise

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in raise_from(e)

IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
```

It do recognize my project ID when I call it as table, but when I run it as query I get this error.

I tried to figure it out and went through many sites for an answer but couldn't get a clear answer for it.

Help is much appreciated... Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you avoid using queries and just use the table option?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from google.cloud import bigquery
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('bq')
    .master('local[4]')
    .config('parentProject', 'google-project-ID')
    .config('spark.jars', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/jarlocation.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
)
client = bigquery.Client()
table_list = 'dataset.schema'
tables = client.list_tables(table_list)

for table in tables:
   tlist = tlist.append(table)

for i in tlist:
    df = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/bigqueryapi.json") \
      .option("parentProject", "google-project-ID") \
      .option("project", "Dataset-Name") \
      .option("table","dataset.schema." + str(i)) \
      .load()
    df.show()
```

Comment: What if I need to unnest few nested columns in the table I get from BigQuery through dataframe using query option while reading the dataframe!?

Comment: @NaveenB please ask another question. this is too far away from the current question and there is not enough space to answer it here.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same exception but because I wasn't specifying the config value `parentProject` which is the BigQuery project ID I'm connecting to